# Tizen Emulator Consumes 100% CPU

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I just started to learn Tizen native development. I use Tizen SDK Version **2.2.0** with build id **20130708-1956** on OSX run at early 2011 MBP.
Everything works fine in SDK setup process, but when I run Tizen emulator, it always make my CPU works 100%, causing my mac getting warmer, and even sometimes just hangs.

[image: 100% CPU]

This is my emulator setting:
[image: Emulator setting]
What's wrong with my configuration? Is the emulator supposed to use 100% CPU like that?

**UPDATE:** I Use OSX Mavericks.

Comment: I have the same Problem, thats why I prefer to test with the samsung's  remote test lab: http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab

Comment: Wow, thanks, its a very good info. Just tried it and got confuse because I don't khow how to generate the *.tpk file to be installed in RTL Client. *go to google first :D

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that CPU virtualization indicator. On Windows it says "ON"/"OFF", but here it says "Disable". If "Disable" means "Disabled", then the performance of the emulator is likely to be quite poor and that might drive up CPU usage.

Comment: @Michael: Just try to run the emulator using CPU-VT enabled, emulator works better but still, got 100% CPU with warmer laptop.. :(

Comment: There should be "Build package" option in context menu on project.